# What is this gelatinous substance by my window frame?

Tags: drywall, window-frame

I'm painting my bedroom.   There is a small hole in the wall adjacent to my window frame. The hole is filled with a substance, it looks like it might be covering something. It's soft to the touch, but not sticky.  Ultimately I'm hoping to spackle and paint over this.

What is this substance?

[image: close up of substance]
[image: gelatinous substance]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be silicone; could be polyurethane. If it’s silicone, it’ll reject being painted and spackle won’t stick to it.

Give it a dab of paint and see if it sticks. If it doesn’t, and you want it to look nice, you’ll have to dig it out, apply paintable filler and so on.